# In vivo delivery of ssDNA

Tags: dna, gene-therapy

I am looking for a system with which I can deliver (large quantities of) ssDNA *in vivo* (say in mice). I do not know whether it is of importance but the 5' end of the ssDNA fragments are assumed to be phosphorylated.

If you could suggest some efficient delivery systems to me I would be very delighted.

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Small ssRNA  can be delivered *in-vivo* using a peptide from rabies virus ([1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1261%2Frna.044008.113), [2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature05901); it is quite specific to the brain, though). It should work with ssDNA as well but I don't know of an experiment that has tried it.

Comment: Electroporation!

Comment: Sure, that would be a possibility for cell cultures, but I am looking for a system that can do the job, for instance, in mice.

Comment: @Luigi how can someone perform electroporation _in vivo_?! :O

Comment: @user19099 *In vivo* electroporation is possible but it is very localized.

Comment: @user19099 In vivo electroporation is simple for intramuscular application, just inject the DNA, and then zap the muscle with the electrode. I've seen a paper that used an endoscope to do electroporation inside pig intestine with decent results. Not so good with intravenous injection though. What OP is asking is basically an entire research program.

Comment: @tobias The answer to this is anything but simple, and doesn't really exist yet. Many groups are working on non-viral methods to protect DNA and/or RNA in the circulation, target it to specific tissues, get it taken up efficiently, and then release the cargo in the right compartment of the cell. It's been challenging, and is far from finished. I would suggest looking at [AAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adeno-associated_virus#AAV_genome.2C_transcriptome_and_proteome), as its genome is ssDNA.

Comment: I would also look at [hydrodynamic injection](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10428218), which is good for delivery to hepatocytes, but not very practical for any other organ.

Comment: I agree with @user137 there are no easy answers - especially with 'large quantities'.  ssDNA material may even trigger innate immunity (eg Toll receptors/ interferon).  This [recent work](http://www.immunosensation.de/blog/?p=729) gives just one flavor of possible complications.